# 3-tier architecture (Monolithic?) vs Microservices

Tags: microservices, 3-tier

I'm doing some research about Information Systems Architecture and I found out that there are some different answers about this topic. I found answers here saying that it is wrong to compare 3-tier with Microservices or SOA, because they are different things. However, I read in both IBM and Microsoft websites that the 3-tier architecture is indeed related to the monolithic one and that there is a possibility to modernize apps, using Microservices for a Cloud-Native Architecture

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-with-azure-containers/modernize-existing-apps-to-cloud-optimized/what-about-cloud-native-applications

This is the link to that microsoft page where this last part is explained.

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/four-architecture-choices-for-application-development

IMB also says the same

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely right to compare microservices and monolithic architectures, as they are both systems architectures with important differences that may make one or the other more appropriate in different scenarios. For example, monolithic architectures are considerably easier to develop, deploy and manage, but microservices scale much better. As explained in the Microsoft guide, it is possible to modernize apps with monolithic architectures to varying degrees, but converting to a microservices architecture requires a lot of work and code rewriting.